# Xbmc Media Center won't start

Tags: kodi

I have windows 7 Ultimate and (fresh uninstall/reinstall) my Xbmc media center (current version) won't start: hangs up at xbmc logo.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A total uninstall using [Revo](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and a fresh install solved the problem